# ANTLR4: Unrecognized constant value in a lexer command

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I am learning how to use the "more" lexer command. I typed in the lexer grammar shown in the ANTLR book, page 281:

```
lexer grammar Lexer_To_Test_More_Command ;

LQUOTE : '"'        -> more, mode(STR) ;

WS   : [ \t\r\n]+   -> skip ; 

mode STR ;

STRING : '"'    -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE) ;

TEXT : .        -> more ;
```

Then I created this simple parser to use the lexer:

```
grammar Parser_To_Test_More_Command ;

import Lexer_To_Test_More_Command ;

test: STRING EOF ;
```

Then I opened a DOS window and entered this command:

```
antlr4 Parser_To_Test_More_Command.g4
```

That generated this warning message:

> warning(155): Parser_To_Test_More_Command.g4:3:29: rule LQUOTE
>   contains a lexer command with an unrecognized constant value; lexer
>   interpreters may produce incorrect output

Am I doing something wrong in the lexer or parser?

Answer (score 3):

Combined grammars (which are grammars that start with just `grammar`, instead of `parser grammar` or `lexer grammar`) cannot use lexer modes. Instead of using the `import` feature¹, you should use the `tokenVocab` feature like this:

**Lexer_To_Test_More_Command.g4**:

```
lexer grammar Lexer_To_Test_More_Command;

// lexer rules and modes here
```

**Parser_To_Test_More_Command.g4**:

```
parser grammar Parser_To_Test_More_Command;

options {
  tokenVocab = Lexer_To_Test_More_Command;
}

// parser rules here
```

¹ I actually recommend avoiding the `import` statement altogether in ANTLR. The method I described above is almost always preferable.

Comment: Okay, I made the changes you suggested Sam. I still get this error: Parser_To_Test_More_CommandLexer.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
                case 0: _mode = STR; break;
                               
  symbol:   variable STR

Comment: @RogerCostello The file **Parser_To_Test_More_CommandLexer.java** is left over from when you had a combined grammar. The new source files have slightly different names (specifically, they don't include the **Lexer** or **Parser** suffix). You need to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks again Sam. I cleaned and rebuilt. That solved the symbol problem but led to a different problem. I ran this command from the DOS prompt: grun Parser_To_Test_More_Command test -gui and that generated this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Parser_To_Test_More_Command
        at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:159)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:143) QUESTION: Does grun only work with combined grammars?

Comment: This is exactly what I come across each time I come back to antlr - revert to import statement -> spurious warnings, change to tokenVocab -> ClassCastException. Seems like there should be more documented about what is going on.