# ANTLR4: Any difference between import and tokenVocab?

Tags: parsing, import, grammar, antlr4, lexical-analysis

The `import` statement or the `tokenVocab` option can be put in a parser grammar to reuse a lexer grammar.

Sam Harwell advises to always use `tokenVocab` rather than `import` [1].

Is there any difference between `import` and `tokenVocab`? If there's no difference (and Sam says to use `tokenVocab`), then why have the `import` statement?

> [1] I actually recommend avoiding the import statement altogether in
>   ANTLR. Use the tokenVocab feature instead. [Sam Harwell]

See [ANTLR4: Unrecognized constant value in a lexer command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384215/antlr4-unrecognized-constant-value-in-a-lexer-command)

Answer (score 21):

First, Let's talk about `import`.

What `import` does is similar to `#include` in C/C++ language, which is copying the src to dst. ANTLR4 will try to merge the two grammars if there are conflicts.

Using `import` is kind of frustrating because there are so many constraints:

1. Not every kind of grammar can import every other kind of grammar.

   - Lexer grammars can import lexer grammars.
   - Parser grammars can import parser grammars.
   - Combined grammars can import lexer or parser grammars.
2. When imported, `options` in grammar will be ignored.
3. When imported, `mode` is not allowed in lexer grammar.

So you actually can't import a lexer grammar in a parser grammar, because they are not the same kind. But you can import a lexer in a combined grammar.

Those constraints have narrowed the usage of `import`. I think the best situation to use `import` would be separating a big lexer or parser grammar into several parts, to make it easier to manage.

Now, remember that we can't import a lexer grammar in a parser grammar using `import`? That's why we need `tokenVocab`, which is designed to use a separate lexer in an parser or combined grammar.

The conclusion of above would be:

- In a lexer grammar, you can only use `import`.
- In a parser grammar, you can only use `import` to import another parser grammar. You can only use `tokenVocab` to use another lexer grammar.
- In a combined grammar, you can use both `import` and `tokenVocab`

For the third one, what's the difference now?

The difference is that using `tokenVocab` needs to compile the lexer first, because `tokenVocab` is only a option declaring the need of another grammar. While using `import` does not need that, because it will copy the src to the current grammar.

For example, there are three grammar files:

G1.g4

```
grammar G1;
r: B;
```

G2.g4

```
grammar G2;
import G1
```

G3.g4

```
grammar G3;
options { tokenVocab=G2; }
t: A;
```

If we directly compile G2, it will be OK. But if we try to compile G3, there comes the error:

> error(160): G3.g4:3:21: cannot find tokens file ./G1.tokens

However, if we compile G1 first, there will be G1.tokens. Now compiling G3 would be a success.